# how to delete a directory using php?

Tags: php

I have the folder called install under that i have a file called install.php
I want to delete the install directory 
I have wrote

```
rmdir("install");
```

in install.php but it does not work
can anybody help me and i cant place the install.php file outside the install folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
exec('rm -rf install');
```

This will delete also not empty directory, you still need write permission. Be very careful when doing that.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

As it says right there: the directory **must be empty**, and the **relevant permissions must permit this**. A E_WARNING level error will be generated on failure.

Answer (score 1):

According to PHP manual on [rmdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php), `The directory must be empty, and the relevant permissions must permit this`.

To empty the directory

```
$handler = opendir($directory);
// open directory and walk through the filenames
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
  if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
    unlink($file);
  }

}
// tidy up: close the handler
closedir($handler);
```

To check for relevant permission, use [`fileperms`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php). Usually, `write` permission is suficient for deletion of folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think `rmdir` function is denied in many servers you can use `rename` to rename the dir to any hashed dir

May be you need install dir again:

```
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");
rename("old_name","New_Name");
rename ("install" ,md5(rand()));
http://php.net/rename
```

You can also use `.htaccess` file   `deny from all`

Regards

Comment: `.htaccess` implies `http server access`, not `php access`:) you cant specify `deny from all` to disable the `rename()` function. You may disable some of the functions accessible to php though, but i dont think it will work in `.htaccess`

Comment: thank you for comment , but i didn't mean deny php functions ,  .htaccess will make this dir "install" forbidden , so no one can acces this dir until delete the .htaccess again and can make it addon's in admin panel to reopen the install dir for update :)           and this url say you can disable php functions from .htaccess  `http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-195763.html`